# Whitespaces around PHP tags causing ajax calls to have extra whitespaces

Tags: php, ajax, whitespace

I have a small problem that has been bugging me for quite some time now, but I can't seem to solve it myself. I googled it and didn't really find anything useful. I thought, maybe someone else came across this problem, or will come across it in the future, so we could help each other.

The problem;
I have made a dropdown list, containing projects. Under this dropdown list there is a textarea. When the user selects a project from the dropdown list, its content is loaded in to the textarea. When I add some text to the textarea, it is automatically saved whenever I press the spacebar or enter. The problem is however, that PHP seems to add 2 linebreaks BEFORE the text. I made some screenshots to illustrate this.

1. The first image shows the text in the Mysql database.
2. You can see that it somehow skips the first 2 lines when displaying the content in a textarea. The notepad look is just a background picture I set within the textarea.
3. After adding some text to it and pressing spacebar it saves the content, and in Mysql it skips the first line.
4. In the content textarea it skips a line as you can see in the image.

Screenshots: http://s9.postimg.org/suh6u3a7j/1234.png

Does anyone know why this is happening? And how can I solve it?

Here is is some code;

```
<script>
  $(function(){
  $("textarea[id='projectcontent']").keypress(function(e) {
      //13 maps to the enter key
      if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 32 || e.which == 32 || e.keyCode == 8 || e.which == 8) {
          saveContent();
      }
  });
});
```

```
<script>
        function getContent()
        {
            var mail = $("#email").val();
            var project = $("#projects").val();

            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "/includes/projects.php",
                data : "project=" + project+  "&email=" + mail+ "&mode=get",
                success : function(result)  {  $("#projectcontent").val(result);  }
            });
        }
    </script>

<script>
        function saveContent()
        {
            var mail = $("#email").val();
            var project = $("#projects").val();
            var projectcontent = $("#projectcontent").val();

            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "/includes/projects.php",
                dataTyp: 'html',
                data : "project=" + project+  "&email=" + mail+ "&projectcontent=" +projectcontent+ "&mode=save",
                success : function(result)  {  $("#response").val(result);  }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

And the drop down and textarea

```
<div id="project">
        <?php
        $projects = new project();
        $projects = $projects->getProjects($_SESSION['user']);?>
        <form><select id="projects" onchange="getContent()"><option>Select project</option>
            <?php
            foreach($projects as $project)
            {?>
                <option value="<?php echo $project['id'];?>"><?php echo $project['name']; ?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select><input type="hidden" id="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>" /></form><span id="response"></span><br /><textarea id="projectcontent" onkeydown="enterkey()"></textarea>
        </div>
```

And the PHP code to save the content.

```
//set project content
public function setProjectContent($projectid, $email, $projectcontent) {
    $spc    =   $this->db->prepare('update projects set content=? where id=? and owner=?');
    $spc->execute(array(trim($projectcontent, ""), $projectid, $email));
    if ($spc->rowCount()==1){
        $message = "Saved";
    }
    else {$message = "Not saved";}
    return $message;
}
```

And the PHP code to get the content.

```
//get project content
public function getProjectContent($projectid, $email) {
    $this->projectid= $projectid;
    $this->email = $email;
    $gpc    =   $this->db->prepare('select content from projects where id=? and owner=?');
    $gpc->execute(array($projectid, $email));
    $result =   $gpc->fetch();
    $content = $result['content'];
    return $content;
}
```

EDIT: Ok, problem is solved. This may be of use to someone else;
The problem was simply that I had some white spaces in one of the include files. Removing the white spaces solved this problem!

Comment: Use `trim` if you want to remove leading and/or following 'not visible ' characters in your code.

Comment: Trim doesn't do anything in this case.

Comment: And can we see your PHP code too?

Comment: Are you 100% that it's not related to css margins or paddings?

Comment: Could you provide the code that sets the content of the `textarea`?

Comment: I added the PHP code. But I suspect the jquery to dynamically submit the project content to PHP is the problem.

Comment: Actually I meant the JavaScript code that sets the content of the `textarea`.

Comment: There it is. It's called getContent().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A long shot but I think your PHP code (the one that has the AJAX function or one of it's includes) may have whitelines infront of the `<php` tag (or somewhere else).

Change the php method that your ajax code calls so that it return a hardcoded value. When you test it again, you can be sure that it isn't the inner logic and see if the lines are still there. Example:

```
//get project content
public function getProjectContent($projectid, $email) {
    $this->projectid= $projectid;
    $this->email = $email;
    $gpc    =   $this->db->prepare('select content from projects where id=? and owner=?');
    $gpc->execute(array($projectid, $email));
    $result =   $gpc->fetch();
    $content = $result['content'];
    return "test on first line";
}
```

Edit: for people looking for whitespaces in php files, I made a regex which finds them `(\s\<\?)|(\?\>\s)`.

Comment: I did this, and it still skips the first 2 lines.

Comment: then you should check your PHP files, they might have white spaces in the begin of the file or in the end. Also check the includes

Comment: You were right. I had white spaces at the begin of a include file I totally forgot about. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed your problem!

Answer (score 1):

`$("#projectcontent").val(result);` this is the code that are setting the value to the textarea, correct? then you can `innerHtml()` js function instead. 
Also while saving the textarea content you can do `$.trim($var)` function to trim.